# register custom Windows 10 callto: uri handler

Tags: registry, windows-10

I'm trying to register a custom callto: uri handler in Windows 10.
I've followed this instructions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto]
@="URL:callto"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Roaming\\someFolder\\some.exe\" \"%1%\""
```

It works like a charm under Windows 7, but refuses to work under Window 10.
If I click a callto link in any browser, Windows asks me to choose an application to open the link.

Any hints are welcome.

peggel